# how to set different navbar for my landing page in wordpress

Tags: wordpress, siteorigin

I am learning wordpress and using the siteorign corp free theme(https://demo.siteorigin.com/corp/) I want to be able to achieve the same design as what they have in their demo site. However, I am facing the challenge of setting the color for the navbars. The landing page comes with a dark background and the color of the navbar text is white, so you can see the text. However, the same text color is used for the other pages which are white, causing them to be invisible.

Please, how do I use different navbars for the different pages or edit the navbar for other pages without affecting the landing page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please create a child theme (https://siteorigin.com/corp-documentation/child-theme/)
    and in the header.php file of your child themes check the condition for homepage or 
    not like this.

```
if(is_page('home')){
  // call header
   wp_navmenu();
}
else{
  // call header with custom classes for styling
   wp_navmenu();
}
```